# Parsing JSON string with \u escapes

Tags: python, json, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have a Python service with and endpoint that passes on data to another service, get's back the result and passes it to the requester. There is a filed `message` in the form and if I input a Unicode character - let's say 'GRINNING FACE WITH SMILING EYES' (U+1F601) - I see following in the request form object

`ImmutableMultiDict([('message', u'\U0001f601'),...`

When I get response from the other service, I have this

`{..., u'message': u'\xf0\x9f\x98\x81',...}`

This is then JSONified using json.dumps into

`{..."message": "\u00f0\u009f\u0098\u0081"...}`

Finally, on client, the message string gets parsed into

`ð`

(If I'm not mistaken, Unicode code for that character is `\u00f0`)

So where does it go wrong? It looks like I have a string that gets returned from an external service with utf8 hex escapes. I tried utf8-decoding that string but I get the following error

`return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not inrange(128)`

Comment: `u'\xf0\x9f\x98\x81'` is [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). So something is wrong between step 1 and 2. In order for anyone to solve your problem, they must have access to the [complete code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which yields `{..., u'message': u'\xf0\x9f\x98\x81',...}` when given the input `ImmutableMultiDict([('message', u'\U0001f601'),...`.

Comment: Information is still there. UTF-8 hex representation of :grin: is `0xF0 0x9F 0x98 0x81`, so that appears correct. And if I do `decodeURIComponent(escape(message))` in the client, it gets properly rendered. So, I guess in the end I'm more interested in how to correctly handle this in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle this correctly you need to fix the process that is creating the `u'\xf0\x9f\x98\x81'` mojibake. As noted, those bytes are correct, but they need to be in a plain string (in Python 3 that's a `bytes` string) *not* a Unicode string. We can't give further details without seeing the relevant code.

However, you can extract the byte codes from the mojibake by encoding it as Latin 1, and then decode those bytes as UTF-8 to create proper Unicode:

```
d = {u'message': u'\xf0\x9f\x98\x81'}
for k, v in d.items():
    # Extract bytes from mojibake Unicode
    b = v.encode('latin1')
    # Now decode the extracted bytes as UTF-8
    s = b.decode('UTF-8')
    print k, s
```

**output**

```
message
```

Or in a more compact form:

```
v = u'\xf0\x9f\x98\x81'
s = v.encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')
print(s)
```

That will work in both Python 2 & 3.

---

You should seriously consider migrating to Python 3, where Unicode handling is a lot saner, and you're much less likely to create these kinds of mix-ups.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Unfortunately, I have no control over what I get in response, but maybe I can do something about handling the reposnse itself in a more proper way.

Comment: @alh84001 That `v.encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')` is pretty efficient. Those `.encode` and `.decode` methods are coded in C and I assume they are well-optimized, since they get used quite a lot, so using them is probably faster than using `decodeURIComponent` (which probably calls those methods anyway, after it's finished messing around).

Comment: @alh84001 I guess there's not much else you can do, apart from telling "the other service" that their app is spewing rubbish, get them to read Ned Batchelder's [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), and tell them to get their act together and start using Python 3. :)

Comment: Thanks once again. In the end I discovered that dictionary that I pass onto the service is `POST`ed as a set of query params, instead of in request body. I guess there's an additional layer of encoding there, since when switching to the other option, it works without issues. Thanks on the link as well, I'll surely take a look :)